# Access of global variables in setImmediate in node.js

Tags: node.js, global

Below is a piece of code:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(0, 'hex'); //Global buffer
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  // Concatenate the received data to buffer
  buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, new Buffer(data, 'hex')]);
  setImmediate(function() { // Executed asynchronously
    /*Process messages received in buffer*/
    var messageLength = getMessageLength(buffer);
    while (buffer.length >= messageLength) {
      /*Process message and send response*/
    }
    //Remove message from buffer after processing is done
    buffer.splice(messageLength);
  }) // End of setImmediate
}) //End of socket.on
```

I am using a global variable 'buffer', inside the setImmediate block(executed asynchronously). Is there a guarantee that the global buffer variable does not change(either due to addition of data or deletion of data) during the execution of code in setImmediate block?? If no, how to handle such that the buffer is accessed safely??

Comment: What is your problem? You want buffer is safe(buffer is not used by outer program) when setImmediate is called? If setImmediate func body is sync, you do not need to worry about it, javascript is single thread. If setImmediate func body is async, use closure variable instead of global one.

Answer (score 0):

The oft-repeated saying "NodeJS is single-threaded" means there is no question of "safety" here. Simultaneous accesses to a variable are not possible because simultaneous operations do not occur. Even though the `setImmediate` code is executed asynchronously, that does not mean it is executed as the SAME TIME. It just means it is executed "soon". The parent function can return before this happens - but the parent function is not running when the anonymous `setImmediate` callback is triggered. At that time, the callback is the only thing running.

These operations are thus safe - but for what it's worth, it's not very efficient. NodeJS buffers are fixed-length, which is why you need to need to keep re-allocating a new one to append data. They're suitable for one-time loads but not really ideal for constant append operations. Consider using a readable stream. This allows you to pull out and process any length of data you want at a time, and can return a buffer. But internally it does not constantly re-allocate its storage block for the data read.